# How to change password policy by allowing Non-alphanumeric characters in the password?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I currently am using an IdentityServer4.

Authentication provider is AD.

I implemented the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` interface, consequently its method `ValidateAsync` was implemented.

```
public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
{
    var username = context.UserName;
    var password = context.Password;

    var validation = adAuthProvider.Validate(username, password);
    if (validation.Valid)
    {
        username = Utilities.TrimDomain(username); 
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(username, "pwd");
    } 
    else
    {
        if (validation.ValidationResponseType == ValidationResponseType.Unauthorized)
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(username, "pwd");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result.IsError = validation.ValidationResponseType == ValidationResponseType.Error;
        }
    }

    context.Result.CustomResponse = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    context.Result.CustomResponse.Add("ValidationResponse", validation);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

An implementation of Validate method in AdAuthProvider class

```
public ValidationResponse Validate(string username, string password)
{
    var validation = new ValidationResponse { Valid = false };

    var ad = GetActiveDirectoryConfiguration(username);

    using (var connection = ldapProvider.Connect(ad.Url, ad.Port))
    {
        username = username;

        var userLoginWithDomainFromConfig = $"{ ad.DistinguishedName }@{ ad.Url }";

        connection.Login(userLoginWithDomainFromConfig, ad.Password);

        //try to login
        connection.Login($"{username}@{ad.Url}", password);
        validation.Valid = true;           
    }

    return validation;
}
```

How to change password policy by allowing Non-alphanumeric characters in the password?

Comment: Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What way should I search ?

Comment: This doesn't look like the validation of an account creation, but rather the authorization at the authority server... Did you write this code?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anything to do with identityserver4 really. I'd strongly suggest not using the resource owner password grant type though if it can be avoided.